# Unable to reproduce TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari

Google Analytics shows that ~12% of our total users are affected by a Javascript bug of:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object`

90% of the browsers are Safari 7534.48.3, 10% are Mozilla compatible agent.  75% of the errors come from iPhones, 23% from iPads.  1% from Macintosh, the other 2% is from iPod etc.  None of the devices run Linux or Windows.

I have tried enabling debug mode in safari on both an iPhone and iPad but not able to reproduce the bug.

[Here is a link to a page Google Analytics claims is showing the error](http://myschoolholidays.com/Birmingham).  If anyone can consistently reproduce the error here I will be super happy because just a line number would be enough to get me started debugging.

Can anyone think of any other ways I can try to debug this?  Thanks all

For the curious among us I'm using [this code to send errors to GA](http://mclear.co.uk/2012/04/09/send-javascript-client-errors-to-google-analytics/) -- **Warning**: Possible self promotion.

**Update:**  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'safari.self.tab.canLoad')

Managed to get that out of it once when clicking around, mostly on an iphone whilst clicking "Change country.."

**Update:** Solved this by making sure the element was available in the dom.  Turns out the ajax call on success was trying to write to an element that wasn't available.

I have kept a solid record of [Unable to reproduce TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object here](http://mclear.co.uk/2012/04/13/unable-to-reproduce-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object/)

Comment: So, what's the file and line the error appears? Your code sends that to GA, too.

Comment: undefined:0 ..  :(  -- Chocolate teapot comes to mind...

Comment: @JohnMcLear: if you found the answer, I think it's better you post it as an answer and approve it (it's allowed), instead of simply updating your question, as it looks like it's still active (unanswered) when it's not.

Comment: @JohnMcLear: as writing this comment, you were last seen 3 hours ago. So could you just follow the above advise already dating nearly 3 years ago and answer yourself to mark that question as answered?

Comment: if you want determine function undefined this type is not found only on typescript from interfaces, but if question and clone, modify such function. TypeError: 'undefined'  is declarative. no has been converted in an object.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined

The undefined type has only one value: undefined. It’s the default value that all variables have after a declaration if no value is assigned to them. You can also assign the value undefined to any variable, but in general, this should be avoided, because if we need to mark a variable as not holding any meaningful value, we should use null.

```
Let declaredVar;
console.log(typeof declaredVar); // -> undefined

declaredVar = 5;
console.log(typeof declaredVar); // -> number

declaredVar = undefined;
console.log(typeof declaredVar); // -> undefined

The undefined value can also be returned by the typeof operator when a non-existent variable is used as an argument.

Console.log(typeof notDeclaredVar); // -> undefined
console.log(notDeclaredVar); // -> Uncaught ReferenceError: notDeclared is not defined
```

Answer (score -4):

In your functions.js, you have this:

```
storage_get = function(key) {
  var store = (window.SAFARI ? safari.extension.settings : localStorage);
  var json = store.getItem(key);
  if (json == null)
    return undefined;
  try {
    return JSON.parse(json);
  } catch (e) {
    log("Couldn't parse json for " + key);
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

`undefined` is NOT a JavaScript keyword. It's a variable that (most of the time) happens to be undefined. You can't use `undefined` like this. Consider what would happen if you replaced it with `pinkelephant`, as that is the exact thing that's happening here.

Comment: This is the weird thing, I don't see functions.js...  What source is functions.js for you?  IE is it coming from cloudflare, google or sharethis?

Comment: Using `pinkelephant` would throw a ReferenceError, using `undefined` does not and simply returns the `undefined` value. Plus, I'm pretty sure you're looking at Chrome AdBlock extension's code: http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/source/browse/trunk/functions.js?r=3645#85 :)

Comment: Haha good point :) Well, it was the only `undefined` I could find... Perhaps that is the answer to his problem though - browser extensions with bugs?

Comment: you don't just replace undefined with pinkelephant, you declare an undefined variable named pinkelephant, such as "var pinkelephant;" and then instead of doing "return undefined;" THEN you can do "return pinkelephant;"

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct.  According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp there is such a thing as "undefined" that is properly supported by all major browsers.

Comment: `undefined` has been a global property with the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }` since ECMAScript 5. It cannot be reassigned. You could technically declare a local variable with that name, but uh, don't? And if you have malicious code doing that, you have bigger problems to solve.